# How to Set the Transaction Isolation level in a Table Value Multi Function

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, functions, isolation-level

How do I set the transaction isolation level within in a table value multi function? I know it can be done in a stored procedure.

```
create function dbo.Test()
RETURNS @TestTable Table (test varchar(1000))
AS 
begin

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
```

I am receiving error below:

```
Msg 443, Level 16, State 15, Procedure abcde, Line 12
Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL' within a function.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't set the transaction isolation level inside a function.  You can use lock hints on the queries used in the functions instead.

Although you should really avoid using either READ UNCOMMITTED or the `nolock` lock hint.